# How can I fix a scratch on a mirror?

Tags: repair, mirror

I designed a wardrobe for my new house with mirrors on the doors. The project was executed, and after that I see a scratch on one mirror.

The mirrors have 5mm thickness. The scratch is like a line with about 2cm length. If you touch it with your fingernails, you can feel that it isn't so deep.

Does someone know any way to fix this mirror issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can feel the scratch with your finger nail then there is a good chance that it is too deep to remove by yourself, but you can certainly try!  Removing scratches from glass is similar to removing them from car paint - you use a polishing compound (made for glass) and ideally an orbital polisher to try and remove the scratch (lots of muscle power works too).  Make sure the area is very clean before you start and that all polishing pads, cloths, etc. are also very clean.  If there is any dirt then when you start polishing, you will end up scratching the glass even more by grinding the dirt into the surface.

Comment: Is Cerium Oxide Glass Polishing Compound the polishing compound your referring to?

Is this appropriate for very faint hairline scratches in mirrors and windows panes?

Comment: I'll survive with that scratch... It will probably become worse, since I'm not very good on that kind of delicate task :)